# Validate arbitrary length object with simple schema

Tags: meteor

I have a `Players` collection and a `Games` collection. I want to construct a data structure that looks as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "1234",
  "accounts": {
    "battlenet": "blah#1234"
  },
  "games": {
    "overwatch": {
      "class": "Hanzo",
      "timePlayed": ISODate
    },
    "world-of-warcraft": {
      "class": "Shaman",
      "timePlayed": ISODate
    }
  }
}
```

`games` is an object, where every key refers to a specific document in the `Games` collection's slug attribute. Every value is a sub-schema definition with autoValues.

I can't find any good way to create validation in such a way that it updates an autoform correctly without weird coersion of data. Is there any way to accomplish this validation with simple schema?

Comment: You're using a key as data which is not great practice. You'd be better off with `games: { name: "overwatch", class: "Hanzo", timePlayed: ISODate}

Comment: Then how would you have multiple of them? Arrays also seem to be very annoying to deal with. Seems like the `meteor roles` package does use this pattern and it has been working much better for me

Comment: Use an array! In simple-schema you'd have `games: [gameSchema]` and then you'd define `gameSchema` to have `{name: String, class: String, timePlayed: Date}`

Comment: That makes updating a single entry very irritating when you have to filter them on the server